# Python Selenium error Element is not clickable at point

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website with selenium on python I keep getting this error every time I try to click on a dropdown button that is inside a div tag can some help me please the error is 'Element is not clickable at point (1341, 240)' below is the website

'https://tennisinsight.com/player/56330/andrea-gamiz/'

if you scroll to the bottom of the page, I am trying to click on the duration dropdown options in the match stats sections. below is my code so far

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    small_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

    driver.execute_script('window.open("https://tennisinsight.com/player/56330/andrea-gamiz/","_self")')
    driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='75%'")
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    html.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(3)   
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ' //*[@id="matchStatsDuration"]')))
    element.click()
```

Comment: Try to use this XPath in the last line:

    '//*[@id="matchStatsDuration"]'

, Let me know if it works

Comment: @LightYagami nah it is still not working that is what i had it as before

Comment: Did you replace entire XPath by this?

Comment: @LightYagami yeah i have edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple approach that I would follow to select the items from this list.

```
# select Month from the list.
element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='matchStatsDuration']/option[.='Month']")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

By this way I don't have to worry about the overlaying top menu, which is obstructing the click on the list element.

Comment: hey it works but i am also trying to click on the go button but i get the same error can u help me, please

Comment: Just add this code `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Go']"))`

Comment: hey sorry just one more thing

Comment: It will trigger the javascript. Basically in the above comment we are clicking on the button with javascript. So, we don't have to worry if the element is overlayed with some other element.